# Cant use findAll() function

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

can any body tell me why is error

```
html_content = get_html_content(test)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    productDetail = []
    product = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"s-result-item"})
    for pd in product:
        product = pd.find("div",class_="s-impression-counter")
        product_name = product.find('span',class_="a-text-normal").text
        productDetail.append(product_name)
        print(productDetail)
```

it appears `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

i know the problem is in the `product` variable, but if i not allow to use `findAll()`, what should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `product` variable in your `for` loop directly after its assignment.

On a side note, you should be using the updated `find_all()` method - this is exactly the same but it conforms to the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Try this instead: -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = get_html_content(test)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
productDetail = []
all_products = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"s-result-item"})

for pd in all_products:
    product = pd.find("div",class_="s-impression-counter")
    product_name = product.find('span',class_="a-text-normal").text 
    productDetail.append(product_name)
    print(productDetail)
```

Note I have changed your original `product` variable to `all_products` to ensure there is a distinction between the variables.

Comment: still not working

Comment: What URL are you are trying to scrape? What is the error now?

Comment: still same, i try to scrape eccomerce website

Comment: Can you share the URL

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=snacks&ref=nb_sb_noss_2

Comment: can you tell me where i wrong

Comment: You are not targeting the correct tags in the HTML to get your desired output. You need to resolve this before anything else.

Comment: but, when i print and i check in cprompt its available

Comment: but when i try to remove .text(), it work

Comment: but it return none

Comment: Ouh no, its realy not targetting anything